# Get last return value

Tags: javascript, node.js

In nodeJS terminal, I can enter this expression and have as a return 'true':

```
> var x = true; x;
true
```

How can I capture this return value in a variable, **without changing the expression**?

The following is not working:

```
> var y = (var x = true; x)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token var
```

Comment: You haven't entered an _expression_ - you've entered two _statements_

Comment: using `eval` ? :)   This question is unclear, you mean you want to have some chars before and some after ? Why ?

Comment: @dystroy: I noticed eval is working. I would like the exact behavior of eval, but without using it (the expression is not a string, it's already code). I fear eval would give me a performance problem (code is in a deep loop)

Comment: Is it a quiz question ? It looks so far from anything useful. It might be a [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: @dystroy: no it is not. My problem is real.

Comment: try this code : var y = (x = true, x);

Comment: @AhbapAldirmaz you just made `x` global.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In node REPL, you can just use `_` :

```
> var x = true; x;
true
> var y = _
undefined
> y
true
```

Comment: This replies to the question, and I can only accept it. But my question was indeed for use in a script, not in terminal. I would be glad to find a solution useable not only in Node REPL.

Comment: *"In nodeJS terminal"*... You should consider asking a different and clearer question, with an explanation of the context. Are you injecting code ?

Comment: @sdenel You might want to come explain your need in [the JS chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript)

Comment: @dystroy: I am injecting code, but at a higher level. I build a Javascript code as a string, and eventually trap it in vm.runInNewContext().

Comment: Parsing it would probably be an easier way to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a statement as an expression.

`x = true` is an expression, and `x` is also an expression. `var x = true` is not an expression, it's a statement.

To use the expression you would declare the variable `x` first. The value of an assignment expression is the value that was assigned, so you don't need to put `x;` after the assignment (which helps as that makes it a statement):

```
var x; var y = (x = true);
```